# Closing VS Code welcome screen after opening a folder/workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VS Code used to automatically close the welcome screen after opening a folder or workspace. After upgrading to the latest version, it no longer closes it and the welcome screen stays open.

I'm not sure what version I was using before upgrade but I think there's a setting somewhere to control this behavior.

Does anyone know where I can change this setting so that welcome screen automatically opens when I start VS Code but auto-closes after opening a folder or workspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There s a way.

Open VS Code and move to the settings page.

File Menu/Preferences/Settings
[image: Settings Page]

And then type welcome to search option key. After that you could see select option for welcome page when IDE loads.

[image: Welcome Page]

Now choose your favorite one.

[image: Select Options]

Your choice)

Comment: `welcomePageInEmptyWorkbench` option gives me the behavior I want. Thank you!